# Binding .Jar lib for Xamarin

Tags: android, jar, xamarin.android, lib

I’m working on warehouse mobile app and I have too many problems when I’m using EditText to scan a products.

I found a library for my device(Kcosit v720), but it’s in .jar for Android Studio, while I’m using Xamarin.Android.

I need to get that lib into my project. I red some topics, on microsoft forum, how to build .jar into xamarin project.
I was half success, i have .dll added into main project references. HOW CAN I BUILT THAT LIB i attached to this post?

I can’t get a list of commands from the lib and also I’m not sure, if the .jar sdk I’m using is really sdk, and i’m not able to check it.

Comment: Your question is vague, What exactly is the issue that you are facing can you be a little clear?

Comment: Edited + The thing is, that there are 3 files in SDK and manual in chinese, so i dont know which to use and how to include it to the project. I Made .dll, added to references and shat niw ?

Comment: @iLukeeY, According to your description, you already have .jar in Android Studio, if you want to use this in Xamarin.Android, you  can package a .JAR  in a Java Bindings Library so that its functionality is available to Xamarin.Android apps. More detailed info, you can take a look:[Binding a .JAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar)

Comment: Yep, i tried that, but i was unsucessful. I can't even include it, or just don't know which location to use. And of course, there could be problem with .jar, cause there is not exactly written, which .jar is library, so i'm not sure, if i chose the correct one.

Comment: @iLukeeY, I donwload your SDk, and I guess that you can get .java file from Barcoder_V2.0.0-20180531-01\SDLgui\src path.There are multiple .Java files.

Comment: Do you think, that bardocereader.jar should work ?

Comment: @iLukeeY, there are many .java files, but I don't which you want to use, and what are the functions of these java, where you get this sdk, please check wheather there are some info.